# How to upload file just after selecting the file from the file dialog?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I want to upload an image just after the user select it from the dialog, not using another submit button? how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but I believe you could submit using javascript.  Hook the js function to the [onChange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event of the [file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object?

There also appears to be an [input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event <- this article shows how to hook the event also.

To submit the form see [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)